# rolling sum over the last 2 seconds

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mytime' : [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:12.340'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:13.0'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:15.342'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:16.42'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:28.742')],
                    'myvalue' : [1,2,np.NaN,3,1],
                    'mychart' : ['a','b','c','d','e']})

df.set_index('mytime', inplace = True)
df
Out[142]: 
                        mychart  myvalue
mytime                                  
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340       a      1.0
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000       b      2.0
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342       c      NaN
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420       d      3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742       e      1.0
```

Here I want to use `rolling` to compute the rolling sum of `myvalue` over the **last 2 seconds.**

Yes, the last two seconds, not the last two observations :)

This is supposed to work, but the two similar calls give different results

```
df['myrol1'] = df.myvalue.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').apply(lambda x: x.sum())
df['myrol2'] = df.myvalue.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').sum()

df
Out[152]: 
                        mychart  myvalue  myrol1  myrol2
mytime                                                  
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340       a      1.0     1.0     1.0
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000       b      2.0     3.0     3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342       c      NaN     NaN     NaN
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420       d      3.0     NaN     3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742       e      1.0     1.0     1.0
```

What is going on with `apply` here? Anything using `apply` seems to be buggy here.
For instance :

```
df.mychart.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
Out[160]: 
mytime
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340    a
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000    b
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342    c
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420    d
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742    e
Name: mychart, dtype: object
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check `np.nansum`

```
df.myvalue.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').apply(lambda x: np.nansum(x))
Out[248]: 
mytime
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340    1.0
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000    3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342    NaN
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420    3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742    1.0
Name: myvalue, dtype: float64
```

Since you have `NaN` in original values and simple `sum` will return `NaN`

```
np.sum([0.5, np.nan])
Out[249]: nan
np.nansum([0.5, np.nan])
Out[250]: 0.5
```

Comment: very interesting wen. so the issue is the function inside the `apply`? but what about the ' '.join(x)  one then?

Comment: This can also be fixed by adding `raw=False` to the apply function, ensuring that it uses the `Series` representation and not a numpy array

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ try with raw=False in rolling apply

Comment: I get `TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object`

Comment: @ALollz ? @Wen?

Comment: that may be worth another question I think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657429/rolling-with-string-variables