# rolling with string variables

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'mytime' : [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:12.340'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:13.0'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:15.342'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:16.42'),
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 14:34:28.742')],
                    'myvalue' : [1,2,np.NaN,3,1],
                    'mychart' : ['a','b','c','d','e']})

df.set_index('mytime', inplace = True)

df
Out[15]: 
                        mychart  myvalue
mytime                                  
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340       a      1.0
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000       b      2.0
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342       c      NaN
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420       d      3.0
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742       e      1.0
```

Here I want to `concatenate` the strings in `mychart` using the values in the last **2 seconds** (not the last two observations).

Unfortunately, both attempts below fail miserably

```
df.mychart.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), raw = False)
df.mychart.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').apply(lambda x: (x + ' ').cumsum(), raw = False)

TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object
```

Are we finally hitting the limits of what `Pandas 23.4` can do? :)
Thanks!

Comment: pandas knows no limits.

Comment: as far as I know rolling does not work for the object type

Comment: sob. that would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `df.Rolling` will support this. Instead, can you resample to 1 sec intervals and then just concat every value with the row after it?

You can then merge the result back using `merge_asof`:

```
v = df.resample('1s').agg(''.join)
pd.merge_asof(df, 
              v.add(v.shift(-1)).rename({'mychart': 'res'}, axis=1), 
              left_index=True, 
              right_index=True)

                         myvalue mychart  res
mytime                                       
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340      1.0       a   ab
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000      2.0       b    b
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342      NaN       c   cd
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420      3.0       d    d
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742      1.0       e  NaN
```

Comment: but how do you re-insert that to the original dataframe?

Comment: and actually this does not really work, because I have sub-second frequencies here. Using resample I lose this granularity unfortunately

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I think you can merge the rows back with `pd.merge_asof`. Also, that is unfortunate to hear. You may be SOL :-(

Comment: hi coldspeed I think you deleted the part where you `resample`

Answer (score 2):

A little bit over thinking , and only work for when rolling result have two concat together , you can work a little bit more and build up your own function and include all the possible rolling number and size

```
df['newmap']=np.arange(len(df)) # vassign new column
d=dict(zip(df['newmap'].astype(str),df.mychart))# create dict for replace
df['rollingstring']=df.newmap.rolling(window = '2s', closed = 'right').sum().astype(int)

df['newmap']=df['newmap'].astype(str)

df['rollingstring']=df['rollingstring'].astype(str)
# this part can be replace with a function⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇
df.loc[df.rollingstring!=df.newmap,'rollingstring']=(df.rollingstring.astype(int).sub(1)/2).astype(int).astype(str)+','+(df.rollingstring.astype(int).add(1)/2).astype(int).astype(str)


df.rollingstring.replace(d,regex=True)
Out[355]: 
mytime
2018-01-01 14:34:12.340      a
2018-01-01 14:34:13.000      b
2018-01-01 14:34:15.342      c
2018-01-01 14:34:16.420    c,d
2018-01-01 14:34:28.742      e
Name: rollingstring, dtype: object
```